# How to pass your POST to another URL using Flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I am trying to get some phrase from the user, and when he/she will press "submit" i want to redirect him/her to another page with his/her name, using Flask. Here is my Python code:

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, render_template, request, session, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods = ["POST", "GET"])
def login():
    if request.method == "POST":
        user = request.form["name"]
        return redirect(url_for("success", name=user))
    else:
        return render_template("login.html")

@app.route("/success", methods = ["POST", "GET"])
def success():
    user = request.form.get('name')
    return render_template("success.html", name=user)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run("0.0.0.0", 8080)
```

So when i go to my site i am going to "else" branch and do: "render_template("login.html")". Then if i press submit i go into "if" where i am trying to redirect the user to "success.html". Here is my login.html:

```
<html>
   <body>

      <form action = "http://ide50-zahar-zagrava.cs50.io:8080/" method = "post">
         <p>Enter Name:</p>
         <p><input type = "text" name = "name" /></p>
         <p><input type = "submit" value = "submit" /></p>
      </form>

   </body>
</html>
```

And succes.html:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello {{ name }}!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

But insted of saying: "Hello " it says: "Hello None".
My main question is how to pass data from one page to another?
I am completely new at Flask and Python, so i can't figure out what's going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `action` from `form` is wrong.you are sending the form to the index page. you could edit it like:

```
<form action="{{ url_for('success') }}" method="post">
```

this way, your form will be sent to the success method.

Comment: Thank you so much! You saved my life :D. So form action="some address" specifies to what address should i sent this information? Right? It fills in my request.form value with some data?

Comment: yup, you can use developer tools(ctrl+shift+q) to see the POST data that are being sent.